# The value of Admin scope can't be empty

Tags: attributes, magento2.4.5

We have created Multiple Select Attribute with 3 values, it displaying in product edit page in backend as below :

[image]

Now we want to create one more option for that attribute and that value should be empty , when i created with empty value and tried to save , i got error as : **The value of Admin scope can't be empty.**

[image]

error  message :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You cannot add a null value to the admin value input due to restrictions imposed by the Magento system. If you provide no input, you can add a zero value. Alternatively, you have the option to customize the Magento admin validation to handle null values differently.**

*This validation message is displayed in the file located below:*

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Attribute/Validate.php
```

Comment: why we wanted to create empty attribute value is because we set a condition before that if(value = empty), than only it should display.

Comment: before we were using dropdown, at that time it was working,  as now we changed to multiple-select instead of dropdown

Comment: @BabyinMagento Yes, it can be achieved without adding a null option to the admin value. When no option is selected, it always returns null.

Comment: @BabyinMagento If the solution works for you, please consider accepting the answer. It can be beneficial for other users facing similar issues.